# Could not install from "folder" as it does not contain a package.json file

Tags: angular, npm

I am trying to run NPM package locally using test Angular project. Angular project has this package.json.
`folder` has `package.json` and `package-lock.json` but still its giving error for not found package.json.

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@username/packagename": "file:./folder",
}
```

I have folder like inside NPM package :

```
 - packagename
    - folder
    - folder-test ( Angular project where i am trying command)
```

I tried running `npm install -S` and `npm install -save` Refering to https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#local-paths

This error i am getting while running `npm install -S`

Comment: what do you have inside your package.json? What's the error message when you run `npm install`? Check your `npm` version using `npm --version`

Comment: Npm install all install but only get message for this folder consider this has one package which I want to it as locally